# Can file time stamps be used to define dependencies in Psake PowerShell makefiles?

Tags: powershell, makefile, psake

From what I have seen Psake domain specific PowerShell scripts do not evaluate if dependent objects really need to be built - instead the dependent objects are always evaluated in order.

Is there a way to implement dependencies so that the script to build a make target, such as a file, is only executed if any of the dependent files are newer than the target file?

I experimented with precondition and post condition, with limited success but this seems like a standard requirement and is in every UNIX style "make" I've used in the past.  It feels like I am missing something obvious.  Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Psake does not have such tools. The similar PowerShell build tool [Invoke-Build](https://github.com/nightroman/Invoke-Build) does. You may try it if "incremental" tasks are important for your build scripts. See its wiki pages

- [Incremental Tasks](https://github.com/nightroman/Invoke-Build/wiki/Incremental-Tasks)
- [Partial Incremental Tasks](https://github.com/nightroman/Invoke-Build/wiki/Partial-Incremental-Tasks)

Comment: That's very helpful - I'll try it out and see how capable it is.  At first glance it looks good.

Comment: I've made good progress with this, and have moved my build over to Invoke-Build.  Thanks for putting this together - very helpful.  Of course I now have another question!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568879/how-to-create-dynamic-build-tasks-with-invoke-build-in-powershell